# Upload image with a title

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to upload a Data to the mongoDb using React, nodejs and express. I wrote a code but when i attach the image it will shows me an error but without the image data will store in database

this is my React code....

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class Register extends Component {
state = {
name: "",
email: "",
password: "",
password2: "",
errors: null,
image: null,
imageName: null
};

onChange = e => {
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
});
};

onChangeImage = async(e) =>{
console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
await this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  image: e.target.files[0],
  imageName: e.target.files[0].name
 });
 }

 onSubmit = async e => {

e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  errors: null
});
if (this.state.password !== this.state.password2) {
  this.setState({
    errors: "Password and Confirm Password Are Invalid"
  });
} else {


  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.state.image);
    const newUser = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      name: this.state.name,
      image: fd,
    };
    console.log(this.state.image);
    const body = newUser;
    const res = await axios.post('api/addUser', body, config);

    console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    }
    }
    };

    Alert = () => {
    if (this.state.errors != null) {
  return <p className="alert alert-danger">{this.state.errors}</p>;
}
return null;
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign Up</h1>
    <p className="lead">
      <i className="fa fa-user" /> Create Your Account
    </p>

    <form className="form" onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)} 
  encType="multipart/form-data">
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          name="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email Address"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          name="email"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          minLength="6"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          name="password2"
          value={this.state.password2}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          minLength="6"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="file"
          name="image"
          onChange={e => this.onChangeImage(e)}
          minLength="6"
        />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <p className="my-1">
      Already have an account? <Link to="login">Sign In</Link>
    </p>
    {this.Alert()}
    </div>
   );
 }
}

export default Register;
```

And this is My Nodejs Code....

```
const User = require("../../models/User");
const gravatar = require("gravatar");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const path = require('path');


const addUser = app => {
app.post(
"/api/addUser",
[
  check("name", "Name is Required")
    .not()
    .isEmpty(),
  check("email", "Please Enter a Valid Email").isEmail(),
  check(
    "password",
    "Please Enter a Password with 6 or more charecters"
  ).isLength({ min: 6 })
],
async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  try {
    //   if user exists send a error
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    const { image } = req.files;

    console.log(req.body);

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: "User Already Exists" }] });
    }
    // get user avatar
    const avatar = gravatar.url(email, {
      s: "200",
      r: "pg",
      d: "mm"
    });
    await image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, 
 '../public/images/Profile_Images', image.name));
    user = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      avatar,
      image
    });
    console.log(image.name);
    user.image = image.name;
    // ecrypt the password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    await user.save();

    // return jsonweb token
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    };

    jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get("jwtSecret"),
        { expiresIn: 36000 },
        (err, token)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json({ token });
        }
        );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
  }
  );
  };

  module.exports = addUser;
```

How can I solve this? In My User Model Image is Optional But name, email, and
other fields are required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the code above you're not parsing the incoming req properly, because once you add the image to the formdata it becomes `multipart/form-data`. You need something like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for it work. Then you can access both the fields and the image.